# Load a div using header

Tags: php, html

i want to update a "div alone", for processing i am going to a new php page(background processing), so i need to return to the same div but i could able to return to the main page(where the div is), so help me to load to the div directly after update

Comment: not clear what you are trying to do here. explain with an example perhaps?

Comment: simply saying i want to update a "div alone", for processing i am going to a new php page(background processing), so i need to return to the same div but i could able to return to the main page(where the div is), so help me to load to the div  directly after update.

Comment: Search on the web for some tutorials in basic ajax use, you'll find what you need.